# Marking an address in geochart from its name

Tags: google-visualization

I am working on geochart.Is there any example showing how to mark a place,given only its name? I have done the same with geocoordinates,and with city names,country names with pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if Google knows where your place names are. For instance, this code will create a map with no problem of all the locations stated. Give it a try with your data and see if it plots:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Place', 'Popularity'],
    ['Statue of Liberty', 200],
    ['Eiffel Tower', 300],
    ['Big Ben', 400],
    ['Tokyo Tower', 500],
    ['Great Pyramids', 600],
    ['Gobi Desert', 700]
  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, displayMode: 'markers'});
}
```

> [image: Tourist Map of the World]

<sup>While it looks like the Statue of Liberty didn't plot, it's on there, it's just small and pinkish</sup>

Comment: @ jmac i want displayMode:'regions'

Comment: Ah, no, there is no default way to do that. You can run it through a geocoder, then correspond that to a region based on the country name, but that would be 100% outside of the scope of geocharts.

Comment: ok,what about using static maps with colored regions?can we calculate the latitue and longitude of any pixel in that static map?

Comment: Region maps do not use latitude and longitude and do not show points. They simply color regions (svg shapes) based on the country names (or ISO country codes) input. Perhaps you should either edit this question to better clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes i was just trying to get region maps with latitude and longitude and fom your answer i understood that only markers are possible with latitude and longitude.now i want to know about getting latitude and longitude in static maps

Comment: Sorry Raji, I don't understand what you are asking. Could you please try to explain your requirements better in your question? I do not know what you mean by 'getting region maps with latitude and longitude' or what you mean by 'static maps'.

Comment: i understood your comment on egion maps.static map is my next option.and now i want to know how to get lat and long values from static maps.say i'm using it in html file and on mouse over event of map i need to get lat and long values

Comment: Again, I do not know what you mean by 'static maps'. While I am more than happy to help, I cannot help if you cannot clearly explain what you need. Please either [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19240655/1933347) or post a new question clearly explaining what you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266002/get-latitude-and-longitude-from-static-google-map