# Get latitude and longitude from static google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I want to display a [static map](http://xiaoxia.de/upload/google-static-maps-generator-EN.html) and on mouse over the map get latitude and longitude on mouse over the map

Comment: i created static map using the following <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=8.4875, 76.95258&zoom=8&size=500x500&sensor=false">.now this is an image,on mouse over i want to get lat and long value to be displayed in an alert box.

Comment: What happened when you tried drawing it with the interactive geochart?

Comment: when using geochart i can not colour certain regions other than provinces/states

Comment: Raji, I really want to help, but you are not explaining your issue well. Try reading [this](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) to get a good idea on how to ask a good question and try to [edit] your post to make it fit those suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

It needs some calculations, you'll find the required methods in the source of this demo: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates?csw=1

function that implements these calculations for usage with a static map:

```
function FX(lat,//center-latitude of the static-map
            lng,//center-longitude of the static-map
            zoom,//zoom of the static-map
            width,//width of the static-map
            height,//height of the static-map
            mouseX,//x-coordinate of the mouseevent inside the element
            mouseY//y-coordinate of the mouseevent inside the element
            ){


   var x = mouseX-(width/2),
       y = mouseY-(height/2),
       s = Math.min(Math.max(Math.sin(lat * (Math.PI / 180)), -.9999), .9999),
       tiles = 1 << zoom,
       centerPoint={
                    x: 128 + lng * (256/ 360),
                    y: 128 + 0.5 * Math.log((1 + s) / (1 - s)) 
                       *-(256 / (2 * Math.PI))
                   },
       mousePoint={
                    x:(centerPoint.x*tiles)+x,
                    y:(centerPoint.y*tiles)+y
                  },
       mouseLatLng={
                    lat:(2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(((mousePoint.y/tiles) - 128) 
                                        / -(256/ (2 * Math.PI)))) -
                            Math.PI / 2)/ (Math.PI / 180),
                    lng:(((mousePoint.x/tiles) - 128) / (256 / 360))
                   };

      return mouseLatLng;

    }
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/yxf2C/show/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/yxf2C/show/)

Comment: @Avinash Agrawal: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8L33fhd6/show/  the function `FY` returns an object with the properties `point` (which contains the x/y-pixel-coordinates) and `inRange` (it's `true` when the pixel is within the image/staticMap, otherwise `false`)

Comment: Thanks for replying and providing the solution, I will look at it and will revert to you. Thanks again.